# How to condense data to single row starting with timestamp

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a set of data that I need to condense by timestamp.  Given data:

```
06:59:27: Call
06:59:28: Call Info:  Voice
device[iPhone]
    rcv=[10.10.123]
    xmt=[10.10.123]
Media Server[Local]
    A rcv=[10.10.123]
    A xmt=[10.10.123]
06:59:28: Call Transfer
```

I need to shift the lines up so all data is on a single row by timestamp:

```
06:59:27: Call
06:59:28: Call Info:  Voice device[iPhone] rcv=[10.10.123] xmt=[10.10.123] Media Server[Local] A rcv=[10.10.123] A xmt=[10.10.123]
06:59:28: Call Transfer
```

Comment: You say you want your data on a single row, yet you show three rows? You say you want it *"by timestamp"*, yet you have two rows with the same timestamp? It's hard to know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
awk '/^([0-9]{2}:){3}/{if(b)printf "\n";b=1} {printf $0 " "}' filename.txt
```

The spacing on the output is not exactly the same as yours, though:

```
06:59:27: Call 
06:59:28: Call Info:  Voice device[iPhone]     rcv=[10.10.123]     xmt=[10.10.123] Media Server[Local]     A rcv=[10.10.123]     A xmt=[10.10.123] 
06:59:28: Call Transfer
```

If you need the output to have that exact spacing, it would be slightly more complicated. Let me know if you have any questions as to how it works.